# What is the condition needed to make sure that function pointers to imported functions are appropriately initialized by Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

The way an import library is implemented—which is described in [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146652/Creating-Import-Library-from-a-DLL-with-Header-Fil)—kind of surprises me in that function pointers to imported functions are *never* initialized. It is said that—from [a highly acclaimed article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)—these function pointers are somehow considered as an entry within the IAT <s>so that they are appropriately initialized just in time by Windows</s>. What is so special in these function pointers, which looks like trivial function pointers, that makes a compiler treat them as an entry within the IAT?

Comment: This must be based on a misconception, the pointer was already initialized by the linker.  It lives inside the DLL, not the client code.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry about assuming that the function pointers are initialized in run-time. Do you mean to say that the function pointers come from a DLL? However, the link above clearly declares them—both imp_NumberList and imp_LetterList.

Comment: It's not clear what function pointer you're talking about. Are you talking about one declared in C++ code or one created behind the scenes by the linker?

Comment: As far as I know, there is an address table for imported/exported functions. At the time the DLL is loaded, its entries may be updated based on the actual base address the DLL is loaded at. Such update is necessary when the DLL is not loaded at its preferred base address.

Comment: No, the `__imp_Xxx` function pointers are exported as data.  Normal relocation takes care of updating the pointer value if necessary.

Comment: @RossRidge I'm referring to the one declared. The wrapper functions make use of the function pointers—in this case, imp_NumberList and imp_LetterList—in order to call the _real_ function. The problem is that the function pointers has never been initialized, which means that they are to be initialized by a compiler or an operating system. That is, my question is in what condition trivial-looking function pointers can be considered as a function pointer to an imported function.

Comment: @HansPassant Although i have no idea what _relocation_ is, i have a feeling that it is the closest answer to my question. However, what is the least requirement for variables to be taken care of by _relocation_? Does it only need to start with `__imp_`? Then, how can we decide what kind of information—an address of _which_ function—should be updated?

Comment: Relocation is necessary when the DLL can't be loaded at its preferred base address.  The OS loader walks the relocation table that the linker generated and patches addresses inside the DLL.  Not just for the function pointers.  This is all entirely automatic.

Comment: @HansPassant Then, that's not the answer to my question. I want to know why the wrapper functions—NumberList and so on—jumps to where the function pointers—imp_NumberList and so on—that has never been initialized point. Do you agree that imp_NumberList should be initialized at least once _in order to_ reach the original function? Yeah, it is the point where i'm not quite sure. How does a compiler know imp_NumberList should be initialized? What condition turns on a compiler to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that function pointers declared in C++ code that are initialized with pointers to imported functions can be implemented by the C++ compiler. The simplest way, for the C++ compiler, is to initialize the pointer with the address of the stub function in the import library. Alternatively, it can initialize it at runtime using actual address of the function taken from the value stored in the import table.

Consider a DLL written in C++ that exports two functions defined like this:

```
extern "C" void _declspec(dllexport) foo() {
    return;
}

extern "C" void _declspec(dllexport) bar() {
    return;
}
```

When you compile this and create a DLL the linker also creates an import library. An import library is more or less an ordinary library, and a library is just a collection of ordinary object (.OBJ) files. For each exported function the import library defines both a stub function and a import pointer. The stub function calls the imported function through the import pointer. The import pointer is initialized with the address of exported function in the DLL by the operating system.

In pseudocode assembly the import library for the above example DLL would look something like this:

```
_foo:
      jmp [__imp_foo]

_bar:
      jmp [__imp_bar]

__imp_foo DD ?
__imp_bar DD ?
```

(There's also other data in the import library like the name of the DLL and exported functions.)

Now lets say you wrote a C++ program that used this DLL and it contained the following code:

```
extern "C" void foo();
extern "C" void _declspec(dllimport) bar();

void (*ptr_to_foo)() = foo;
void (*ptr_to_bar)() = bar;
```

These two function pointers get initialized in different ways by the Microsoft C++ compiler. The `ptr_to_foo` variable is statically initialized with the address of `foo`, because the compiler doesn't know it's being imported from a DLL. It looks a normal function, so it doesn't do anything special.

The second variable's initialization gets implemented by Microsoft's compiler in a different manner. Since the compiler knows it's an imported function, it bypasses the stub and uses the import pointer directly. Since the value of the import pointer is only known at runtime, the compiler generates initialization code that's executed at program start up (before `main` is called) to load `ptr_to_foo` with the value stored in `__imp_foo`.

When the example program above is linked with the import library for my example DLL is creates an executable that imports the DLL.  This is where the only thing that could be called magical happens. Because of how the import pointers and other data in the import library are defined (specifically by being defined in the ".idata" section) the linker knows what part of the executable is the import table, and stores a pointer to the table in the header of the executable.

When the the operating system loads the executable it sees that it has an import table, and so loads all the DLLs mentioned in it. It then updates the import table so all the import pointers in the executable, as loaded in memory, point to the corresponding exported functions in the loaded DLLs.

Comment: Assume that we are to make an import library, which means we have to declare an import pointer on our own. Given that .def file does not give a name of an import pointer, how does a compiler knows which pointer among them should be treated as an import pointer? Is it the name of a pointer—the prefix imp—that distinguishes itself from other pointers? What happens if, let's say, the name of an import pointer is "aa"? Does it work?

Comment: @user227248 The compiler never sees import libraries, they're created and consumed by the linker. If you were to somehow create an import library yourself you would have to do so in a manner compatible with how the linker creates them. The existence of a .DEF file is irrelevant here. Just like how a function named `foo` is referred to by the symbol `_foo` in object files and libraries, that function's import pointer needs to be named `__imp_foo`.

Comment: What happens if the name of a pointer changes because of name mangling?